# How to customize chrisbanes / ActionBar-PullToRefresh or change the colour of pull to refresh bar

Tags: android, android-layout, pull-to-refresh

i am using the chrisbanes / ActionBar-PullToRefresh from this link https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh and i have created custom list-view and i wan to change the colour of pull to refresh bar and text colour on it as you can see in picture it is in black colour. please anyone guide me.
![enter image description here][1]

Comment: You need to change it into the library for your requirement.

Comment: i have check the library there is no class LoadingLayout.java pull_to_refresh_header_horizontal.xml and pull_to_refresh_header_vertical.xml

Comment: Your library is different than which i have used. Actually you need to try to change into the layout of your pulltoreferesh library.

Comment: they have mentioned that we can customize the header from this link https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/development/samples/stock/res/values/styles.xml but did not worked for me

Comment: the black is not changing as you can see in the pic

Comment: Try to change into the `colors.xml`

Comment: there is style.xml in the lib no colors.xml

Comment: check out into the `values/colors.xml`.

Comment: i think you are using different library i have  attrs.xml , ids.xml, pulltorefreshstrings.xml, style.xml , there is no color.xml

Comment: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.samples.stock I am using this library you can in this video i have used the last one in the Tabs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Change Progress Bar Color:
defaultHeaderTransformer.setProgressBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent_color));

Change Text Color:
<item name="ptrHeaderTitleTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearanceCustomPtrHeaderTitle</item>
<style name="TextAppearanceCustomPtrHeaderTitle" parent="android:TextAppearance.Large">
<item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: hey how to use that defaultHeader class and where to use this statement ?

Comment: DefaultHeaderTransformer transformer = (DefaultHeaderTransformer) mPullToRefreshLayout.getHeaderTransformer();